# Removing an element from an array after clearing its value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to remove an element index from an array once I clear its value.

```
const myArray:string[] = ['123456', '234567']

const editedArray = myArray.map((m) => {
     if('123456' !== m) return m;
     return '';

const myArray = editedArray; // I want to return ['234567'] not ['', '234567]

// Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
```

Comment: Use the filter method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will *always* return an array with the *same* number of elements that it's iterating over. You should use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

```js
const myArr = ['123456', '234567'];

// `filter` accepts a string
function filter(str) {

  // Return a new filtered array that
  // doesn't contain that string
  return myArr.filter(el => {
    return el !== str;
  });

}

console.log(filter('123456'));
```

Comment: Just tried this! Exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Comment: or in one line, `const filter = (str) => myArr.filter(el => el !== str)`

Comment: Yeah, I hate one-liners when I'm trying to explain something in detail, and demonstrate code that's readable. I also don't really like function expressions for this either preferring function declarations for the same reason. @SumanMajhi.

Comment: @andy yup, that make sense 

Answer (score 1):

I think filter is the method you want.

Though not much information was provided in the question itself, map is not the right choice.